# Theories and algorithms for subdivision of surfaces

Tags: c++, opengl, math, geometry

I have the following problem:

Here is how I draw a cube on the screen:

```
void drawCube()
{

    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear color and depth buffers
    glPushAttrib(GL_POLYGON_BIT | GL_ENABLE_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) ;

    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE) ;
    //glDisable(GL_LIGHTING) ;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);                // Begin drawing the color cube with size 3cm x 3.5cm x 4cm
        // Top face (y = 1.0f)
        // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order with normal pointing out
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
        glVertex3f( 1.75f, 1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, 1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, 1.75f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.75f, 1.75f,  1.0f);

        // Bottom face (y = -1.0f)
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     // Orange
        glVertex3f( 1.75f, -1.75f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, -1.75f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, -1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.75f, -1.75f, -4.0f);

        // Front face  (z = 1.0f)
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
        glVertex3f( 1.75f,  1.75f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f,  1.75f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, -1.75f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.75f, -1.75f, 1.0f);

        // Back face (z = -1.0f)
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Yellow
        glVertex3f( 1.75f, -1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, -1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f,  1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.75f,  1.75f, -4.0f);

        // Left face (x = -1.0f)
        glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
        glVertex3f(-1.75f,  1.75f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f,  1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, -1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.75f, -1.75f,  1.0f);

        // Right face (x = 1.0f)
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Magenta
        glVertex3f(1.75f,  1.75f, -4.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.75f,  1.75f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.75f, -1.75f,  1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.75f, -1.75f, -4.0f);
    glEnd();  // End of drawing color-cube


    glPopAttrib() ;
}
```

The question is how can I assign 'sample points' between all vertices?

From my understanding I need to find the distance between vertices and divide it into (say) five equal parts. For the sake of argument, imagine that the space between two vertices is 1, so 5 points will be placed on 0.2 distance from each other. Also they need to be stored in kind of a memory structure (vector/array) so that each one of them can be accessed and translated into screen coordinates at a later stage.

However, how can I do this in C++ in a totally generic way so that it could be applied basically to any distance metrics?

[Here is how the cube looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N4af.png)

Comment: subdividing between 2 points is not enough, you want a grid of points to appear. Indeed there are plenty of possibility (square grid, triangle grid, subdivision patches), and plenty of possible structures from purely custom in C to "official" VBO, passing through quad or triangles strips. So you should be more specific. Or is the question "how to do a surface mesh in OpenGL" ? Or is the question "theories and algorithms for surfaces subdivision" ?

Comment: Yes, you are right I was after a subdivision of a surface. Mykola, though, provided me with a more than sufficient answer. Edited the question title :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my drawBox function, if you want you can modify it to draw different color at each face.

```
void DrawBox(GLfloat fWidth,GLfloat fHeight,GLfloat fDepth,GLint wslices,GLint dslices,GLint stacks)
{
     // Calculate number of primitives on each side of box
     // because we can use different tessalation configurations 
     // we must calculate separate group of box sides 

    int iTopButtonQuads = wslices * dslices * 2; // Calculate number of quads in top and button sides
    int iLeftRightQuads = dslices * stacks * 2; // Calculate number of quads in left and right sides
    int iFrontBackQuads = wslices * stacks * 2; // Calculate number of quads in front and back sides

    // If we consider to use quads as primitive then each primitive will
    // have 4 points, and each point has color, coord and normal attribute.
    // So we create separate array to contain each attibute values.

    float* pfVertices = new float[(iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 3 * 4];
    float* pfColors = new float[(iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 3 * 4];
    float* pfNormals = new float[(iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 3 * 4];

    int iVertexIndex = 0;

    GLfloat Xstep = fWidth / wslices;
    GLfloat Ystep = fHeight / stacks;
    GLfloat Zstep = fDepth / dslices;

    GLfloat firstX = fWidth / 2.0f;
    GLfloat firstY = fHeight / 2.0f;
    GLfloat firstZ = fDepth / 2.0f;

    GLfloat currX = 0.0f;
    GLfloat currY = 0.0f;
    GLfloat currZ = 0.0f;

    GLfloat x_status = 0.0f;
    GLfloat y_status = 0.0f;
    GLfloat z_status = 0.0f;

    // the bottom and the top of the box
    for (currZ = -firstZ, z_status = 0.0f; currZ < firstZ - Zstep / 2.0f; currZ += Zstep, z_status += Zstep)
    {
        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX,-firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,-firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX + Xstep,-firstY,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,-firstY,currZ + Zstep};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }

        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX + Xstep,firstY,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX,firstY,currZ};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,firstY,currZ + Zstep};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }
    }

    // the front and the back of the box
    for (currY = -firstY, y_status = 0.0f; currY < firstY - Ystep / 2.0f ; currY += Ystep, y_status += Ystep)
    {
        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX,currY,firstZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY,firstZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY + Ystep,firstZ};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,currY + Ystep,firstZ};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }

        for (currX = -firstX, x_status = 0.0f; currX < firstX - Xstep / 2.0f; currX += Xstep, x_status += Xstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY + Ystep,-firstZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {currX + Xstep,currY,-firstZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {currX,currY,-firstZ};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {currX,currY + Ystep,-firstZ};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }
    }

    // Right side and the left side of the box
    for (currY = -firstY, y_status = 0.0f; currY < firstY - Ystep / 2.0f; currY += Ystep, y_status += Ystep)
    {
        for (currZ = -firstZ, z_status = 0.0f; currZ < firstZ - Zstep / 2.0f; currZ += Zstep, z_status += Zstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {firstX,currY,currZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {firstX,currY,currZ + Zstep};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }

        for (currZ = -firstZ, z_status = 0.0f; currZ < firstZ - Zstep / 2.0f; currZ += Zstep, z_status += Zstep)
        {
            int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3 * 4;

            float pfNormal[3] = { -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfNormal, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfNormals + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfNormal, 3 * 4);

            float pfColor[3] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f };

            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfColor, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfColors + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfColor, 3 * 4);

            float pfVertex0[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ};
            float pfVertex1[3] = {-firstX,currY,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex2[3] = {-firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ + Zstep};
            float pfVertex3[3] = {-firstX,currY + Ystep,currZ};

            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex, pfVertex0, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 3, pfVertex1, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 6, pfVertex2, 3 * 4);
            memcpy(pfVertices + iCurrentIndex + 9, pfVertex3, 3 * 4);

            iVertexIndex++;
        }
    }

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)pfColors);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)pfNormals);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)pfVertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, (iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    delete [] pfVertices;
    delete [] pfNormals;
    delete [] pfColors;
}
```

the result will be like

[image]

this is the example of usage created arrays, to collect some shape statistics

```
    // Example 
    // Find min-max of shapes coordinates

    // Get coord of first vertex
    float fMinX = pfVertices[0];
    float fMinY = pfVertices[1];
    float fMinZ = pfVertices[2];

    float fMaxX = pfVertices[0];
    float fMaxY = pfVertices[1];
    float fMaxZ = pfVertices[2];

    for (int iVertexIndex = 0; iVertexIndex < (iTopButtonQuads + iLeftRightQuads + iFrontBackQuads) * 4; iVertexIndex++)
    {
        int iCurrentIndex = iVertexIndex * 3; // (x y z) per vertex

        if (pfVertices[iCurrentIndex] < fMinX)
            fMinX = pfVertices[iCurrentIndex];

        if (pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 1] < fMinY)
            fMinY = pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 1];

        if (pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 2] < fMinZ)
            fMinZ = pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 2];

        if (pfVertices[iCurrentIndex] > fMaxX)
            fMaxX = pfVertices[iCurrentIndex];

        if (pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 1] > fMaxY)
            fMaxY = pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 1];

        if (pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 2] > fMaxZ)
            fMaxZ = pfVertices[iCurrentIndex + 2];
    }

    // Create an axes aligned bounding box 
    // by simply drawing inflated min-maxes, that we collect
    // example of using indexed primitives

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        fMinX - 2.0, fMaxY + 2.0, fMaxZ + 2.0,
        fMaxX + 2.0, fMaxY + 2.0, fMaxZ + 2.0,
        fMaxX + 2.0, fMinY - 2.0, fMaxZ + 2.0,
        fMinX - 2.0, fMinY - 2.0, fMaxZ + 2.0,
        fMinX - 2.0, fMaxY + 2.0, fMinZ - 2.0,
        fMaxX + 2.0, fMaxY + 2.0, fMinZ - 2.0,
        fMaxX + 2.0, fMinY - 2.0, fMinZ - 2.0,
        fMinX - 2.0, fMinY - 2.0, fMinZ - 2.0
    };

    GLint indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 1, 0,
        3, 2, 6, 7,
        5, 4, 7, 6,
        1, 5, 6, 2,
        4, 0, 3, 7 
    };

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)vertices);

    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)indices);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed :)

Comment: you can also add some optimization by grouping opposite sides of the box into one outer 'for' loop

Comment: How can you collect all the boundary points of only visible surfaces into an array?

Comment: You can collect all points by dynamicaly allocated memory of floats, then call glDrawElements or glDrawArrays. To draw only visible surfaces you may select only polygon winding or more complex PVS or BSP algos.

Comment: In order to collect only the boundary points, what I am after? Otherwise for drawing only the visible surfaces I used: glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); and it did the job

Comment: Can you quickly summarize it with words

Comment: I create 3 array wich stores separately 3 components of the point (coords, normals, color values).

Comment: You can access to each point values by its index pfVertices[index * 3] = array of float[3] coords with (x y z). The same is for normals and colors expept the name of arrays which in this point are pfNormals and pfColors.

Comment: You can even go further by adding support of indices and mix values to work with vertex data strides.

Comment: More info about  arrays in OpenGL https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml

Comment: Can you look at this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33152554/scan-lines-for-particle-filter-with-opengl

Comment: I am still struggling on transforming all points from 3D space coordinates to 2D screen coordinates can you help or suggest something? i use gluProject(fMinX, fMinY, fMinZ, modelView, projectionMatrix, viewport, &screenX, &screenY, &screenZ); iteratively for all 8 corners and screenZ is ignored

Comment: If you want to project obj coord to screen coords this is the only way,

Comment: screenZ forms depth buffer value